# C# Complicated Json Deserialize

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize this json but this is complicated json and I couldn't. Actually I tried to create a class in http://json2csharp.com/ but it didn't work again. Can you help me to figure it out

```
    {

    "?xml":{

    "@version":"1.0",

    "@encoding":"utf-8"

    },

    "ArrayOfPerson":{

    "@xmlns:xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",

    "@xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",

    "alert":[

    {

    "@xmlns":"urn:url:taces:numarates",

    "identifier":"489756",

    "sender":"example.com",

    "sent":"2015-08-19T23:44:00+00:00",

    "status":"Actual",

    "msgType":"wait",

    "source":"Company",

    "scope":"Public",

    "info":{

    "category":"known",

    "event":"event created",

    "responseType":"Execute",

    "urgency":"Expected",

    "severity":"Severe",

    "certainty":"Likely",

    "effective":"2015-08-19T23:44:00+00:00",

    "expires":"2015-08-20T00:29:00+00:00",

    "senderName":"Company",

    "headline":"headlineExample",

    "description":" description string ",

    "instruction":" instruction description.",

    "contact":"mail adress",

    "parameter":[

    {
    "valueName":"city",
    "value":"city time"
    },

    {
    "valueName":"severity",
    "value":"High"
    },

    {
    "valueName":"POLYGON",
    "value":"POLYGON ((25.8600349687548 -100.744518850353, 25.8335161877637 
    -100.664518850353, 25.8346209950992 -100.624518850353, 25.8442798845219 
    -100.61828081562, 25.8842798845219 -100.602879447141, 25.9242798845219 
    -100.604707951971, 25.941798102096 -100.624518850353, 25.9243730812152 
    -100.684518850353, 25.9242798845219 -100.684661516991, 25.9095974027013 
    -100.704518850353, 25.9042798845219 -100.710343745251, 25.8642798845219 
    -100.747917201708, 25.8600349687548 -100.744518850353))"
    },

    {
    "valueName":"direction",
    "value":"2"
    },

    {
    "valueName":"speed",
    "value":"27 km"
    }

    ],

    "area":{
    "areaDesc":"Latitude: 25.885, Longitude: -100.664",
    "polygon":"26.1256671949002 -100.814556141911, 25.5230724567197 
    -100.823124650158, 25.5734941016972 -100.397349654998, 26.1574195901602 
    -100.546429706446, 26.1256671949002 -100.814556141911"
    }

    }

    }

    ... array items

    ]
    }
    }
```

Comment: Did you convert this from XML?  Would it be easier to deserialize the XML directly?

Comment: I tried but I don't know how to parse it as xml so I've changed to json and parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your issue is because your JSON property names can't be used as C# variables "as is" therefore json2charp returns names like "invalid-name__@version"

Almost all Json desializers including DataContractJsonSerializers and Json.Net can support custom datamember names. It doesn't need to be identical as property name in your class. Refer to [DataMember attribute on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Alternatively  you can use Json.Net library and JsonReader to manually address properties by name http://insidethecpu.com/2013/06/19/json-parsing/